# Deserialize json in C# for this array json format

Tags: c#, json, api, deserialization, json-deserialization

How to deserialize this json format in C#?

How can we create a model for this type of json string and how to use that model to get the data?

```json
[
     {
         "ID":"HR",
         "Province":"Haryana",
         "Capital":"Chandigarh"
     },
     {
         "ID":"BR",
         "Province":"Bihar",
         "Capital":"Patna"
     }
]
```

Comment: Are you using Newtonsoft Json.net or System.Text.Json (.NET Core 3+)?

Comment: Newtonsoft.json.net

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

var json=...your data

List<State> states = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<State>>(json);
```

or using System.Text.Json

```
List<State> states = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<<List<State>>(json);
```

class

```
     public class State
    {
        public string ID { get; set; }
        public string Province { get; set; }
        public string Capital { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Why don't you simply deserialize it as a `List`? `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<State>>(json)`

Comment: How to deserialize json data from this url in c#? How to create model for this? 
Url-- https://data.covid19india.org/state_district_wise.json